# How do I recursively find nodes in a BST within a range, and return a full list?

Tags: python, list, recursion, binary-search-tree

```
##############################
class Node:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.val = value

###############################
class BinarySearchTree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

def print_tree(node): 
    if node == None:
        return
    print_tree(node.left)
    print_tree(node.right) 
    print(node.val)


#################################################
# Task 1: get_nodes_in_range function
#################################################  
def get_nodes_in_range(node,min,max):
    if node == None:
        return
    get_nodes_in_range(node.left, min, max)
    get_nodes_in_range(node.right, min, max)
    if min <= node.val <= max:
        nodelist.append(node.val)
    return nodelist
    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    BST = BinarySearchTree()
    BST.root = Node(10)
    BST.root.left = Node(5)
    BST.root.right = Node(15)
    BST.root.left.left = Node(2)
    BST.root.left.right = Node(8)
    BST.root.right.left = Node(12)
    BST.root.right.right = Node(20)
    BST.root.right.right.right = Node(25)
    nodelist = []
    print(get_nodes_in_range(BST.root, 6, 20))
```

my get_nodes_in_range function requires a list to be appended to. Is there a way to make this function work without creating a list outside the function? ie. directly returning a list generated recursively?

Asking as this is part of an assignment for school, and although it returns the correct output, it fails the unit test: Unexpected error: name 'nodelist' is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of the problem is you trying to use global variable `nodelist` inside `get_nodes_in_range` function. Your code works when you run it and fails when you import it. Because `__name__` is not equal to `'__main__'` when you import the code. That's how Python works. It is expected and correct behavior.

I suggest the following approach to fix the problem.

```
# just for convinience
def create_bst():
    ans = BinarySearchTree()
    ans.root = Node(10)
    ans.root.left = Node(5)
    ans.root.right = Node(15)
    ans.root.left.left = Node(2)
    ans.root.left.right = Node(8)
    ans.root.right.left = Node(12)
    ans.root.right.right = Node(20)
    ans.root.right.right.right = Node(25)
    return ans

# fix - create a list to store results inside the function
def get_nodes_in_range_1(node, min_value, max_value):

    ans = list()
    if node is None:
        return ans
    if min_value <= node.val <= max_value:
        ans.append(node.val)
    ans.extend(get_nodes_in_range_1(node.left, min_value, max_value))
    ans.extend(get_nodes_in_range_1(node.right, min_value, max_value))

    return ans


if __name__ == '__main__':

    bst = create_bst()

    nodes_in_range_1 = get_nodes_in_range_1(bst.root, 6, 20)
    print(nodes_in_range_1)
```

Answer (score 0):

A common way of doing it is to use a helper function:

```
def get_nodes_in_range(node, lo, hi):
    res = []
    get_nodes_in_range_helper(node, lo, hi, res)
    return res
```

then adjust the `get_nodes_in_range_helper` function to append to `res`:

```
def get_nodes_in_range_helper(node, lo, hi, res):
    if node == None:
        return

    get_nodes_in_range_helper(node.left, lo, hi, res)
    get_nodes_in_range_helper(node.right, lo, hi, res)

    if lo <= node.val <= hi:
        res.append(node.val)
```

(Note: it's probably not a good idea to use `min/max` as variable names as they're built-in Python functions)